# Is it ok for my own function to throw ArgumentCountError in my app in PHP 7.1?

Tags: php

I'll explain my question by an example, however my question is more general as in the title.

I have a variadic function that requires at least 2 parameters. Simplifying, the purpose of it is to build a query that will match a value to one from the params based on the order of them (some kind of priority list). The reason it takes a minimum of 2 parameters is that matching on a single one makes no sense and other method should be used instead. Here's an example:

```
function match(string $firstElement, string ...$moreElements) {
    // build the query here
}
```

For simplicity of the code, I wanted to reduce the signature to

```
function match(string ...$elements) {
    if (count($elements) < 3) throw new \ArgumentCountError();
    // build the query here
}
```

However this met a disapproval from a couple of members from my team arguing that user should be throwing exceptions and never errors. I argued that if that was intention PHP would not allow me to throw errors, but only catch them and the actual difference is the semantics of the error/exception.

Comment: If you do decide to stick with Exceptions, there is http://php.net/manual/en/class.invalidargumentexception.php

Comment: As the `error` class implements the `Throwable` I can't see why you can't use them as they are perfectly catchable in a `try { ... }catch(...)` block. Imho this is just a matter of personal opinion

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, exceptions should be used when an unexpected behaviour encountered during the execution of the script. However, if the result is something expected an exception should not be thrown.

For example, your match function would probably return either false or true depending on the result of the query. If no match was found, you should not throw an exception, you just return a false.

However, the function is expecting a set number of arguments or specific type. So, when a user pass something does not match the function signature, this is an unexpected behaviour, and throwing an error or exception is proper result. And this is the purpose of the [InvalidArgumentException](http://php.net/manual/en/class.invalidargumentexception.php) as pointed in the comments.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, but I was asking about errors, not exceptions.